# Content:// and File:// in android when sharing pictures and videos

Tags: java, android, media

Both these are used by different apps. Facebook shared with File Uris and Whatsapp with Content Uris. If my app can share Videos and pictures, which one should I use?

Also, if my app should accept videos and pictures, for which type should I be prepared? And if for both, should I convert the Content URI into a File Uri or the other way around?

Comment: You should be prepared for both and never convert.

Comment: dimply use `android.support.v4.content.FileProvider`

Answer (score 0):

> If my app can share Videos and pictures, which one should I use?

On Android 7.0+, you have little choice but to share using a `content` `Uri`, such as from `FileProvider`.

On Android 6.0 and older, if the content is on internal storage, you also have to use `FileProvider`, as third-party apps have no access to your portion of internal storage. If the content is on external storage, you could use either `file` or `content`. The older the device, the more likely it is that pre-installed apps will only support `file`.

> if my app should accept videos and pictures, for which type should I be prepared?

Ideally, both. If by "accept" you mean via `ACTION_SEND`, you have no choice but to support both. For `ACTION_VIEW` and `Intent` actions like it, where the data facet of an `Intent` is used for the `Uri`, use the `<data>` element to advertise which scheme(s) you support.

> should I convert the Content URI into a File Uri or the other way around?

Neither. You consume the content from its original source. A `ContentProvider` supports both schemes, for things like `getType()` and `openInputStream()`.

Comment: getActivity().getContentResolver().getType(urinormal) crashes for me if I use it on file:///storage/emulated/0/com.facebook.katana/fb_temp/.facebook_325452438679.jpg

I figured that storage permisison might be necessary, is that correct?

Comment: @Tomhawk: Correct. You need to hold the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, which includes needing to request that permission at runtime on Android 6.0+.

Comment: Ok thanks, that works. As I don't have a Marshmellow device, what would happen if I just define it in the permissions there? It still works on my emulator.

Comment: @Tomhawk: You do not need to request permissions at runtime on Android 5.1 and older. Just have the `<uses-permission>` element in the manifest.